# How do you create a .bundle to store images?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bundle

Actually, I’ve read somewhere that keeping images as bundle would be the proper way to prevent it from being copied from .ipa file. So, I would like to know how to make bundles for images. Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an iOS asset bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888208/how-to-make-an-ios-asset-bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some good advice regarding creating and accessing an asset bundle in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888208/how-to-make-an-ios-asset-bundle).

Comment: I couldn’t believe, its that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nina: yes you are right its not simple task for freshers, But why you need of that you can also just copied in the bundle by just droping it in XCode ...

Comment: @Nina: I want to say you that why you are going to create a bundle by default we can get an application bundle in each app you can store it images there via just drag an drop to xcode and you can see your bundle resource in app target + third tab Build Phase +4th optioncopy bundle resource in XCode 4.5.2 if still you are not getting then add me on skype my username: "himanshu_agnihotri", I will explain you there thanks !!