# How to build an application including a folder for further load on the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, assets, nsbundle

I have a directory structure on my computer i wanted to include into my app bundle:

```
   @"/Users/playra/Desktop/2 DivyaLoka/Собрание Тайн";
```

application starts surf folders, keeping the directory tree, which is visible in the screenshot

[image]

but when using the load

```
self.pathProperty = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

or

```
self.pathProperty = NSHomeDirectory();
```

structure disappears and everything is loaded into one tableView.

How to start an application starting with a folder `**Собрание Тайн**` that is in the sandbox  keeping structure inside for further load on the device?

Comment: Are you running the App on the device or in the simulator? The path @"/Users/playra/Desktop/" will not be available on the device. What do you mean by "tableView"? Is the screenshot from your app? It looks like "Finder".

Comment: @mahaltertin Thank you for reply . Yes i run in the simulator and i know the path for not device. And i ask how to run on the device...

Comment: question not clear enough. Do you want to include your directory structure in the main bundle? Why do you think it is related to sandboxing? The term "architecture" seems not appropriate here.

Comment: @mahaltertin Excuse me. Yes of course you are right directory structure, but i have already found the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888208/how-to-make-an-ios-asset-bundle/5277452#5277452
I created the Bundle and put into one the folder with a directory

Comment: @mahaltertin But Now i cannot load the resource from a bundle. I try get it 

NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"meeting" ofType:@"bundle"];
        
        NSString *filePathPdf = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:theFileName ofType:@"pdf"];

But *filePathPdf is "nil". I tried to load on the device iPhone 5.

Comment: I tried to edit the question. please edit it as well including your new findings. as I see it, it has nothing to do with sandbox. and therefore i don't know an answer.

Comment: @setoffonom : do you want to know how to take build ?

Comment: @mahaltertin Ok Thaks You.

Comment: @VineeshTP Yes. I want.

Answer (score 0):

First choose IOS Device

[image]

Product --> Archive

[image]

Choose Disribute

[image]

Then, Save for nterPrice or Ad-hoc Deployment

[image]

Then choose your certificate and Export

[image]

Then save the build

[image]