# Localized .strings file in a bundle return en.lrproj, even when running in non-English language. Using the same file directly without bundle works

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm currently working on an iOS project in Xcode where I've created a resource bundle containing a translated .strings file (let's call it myTexts.strings). This bundle is then reused in multiple targets (as I plan to add multiple translation files, to better separate specific app areas).

When I try to access a localized string with the following line of code:

```swift
NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "myTexts", bundle: bundle, comment: comment)
```

The string is never found. Additionally, when I attempt to list the available .strings files with the following code:

```swift
bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: "strings", inDirectory: nil)
```

It only returns the file in `en.proj`, even though the app is running in Czech language (i.e., I expect to see `cs.proj`).

However, when I remove the bundle, include the .strings file directly in all targets, and run the app on a device set to Czech, it works perfectly fine — the `bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: "strings", inDirectory: nil)` function correctly lists cs.proj, and the czech string is correctly looked up.

I've checked the structure of my bundle and ensured that it contains the cs.lproj directory. The built app also has the *.lrpoj for all the languages. I'm also confident that I'm initializing my bundle object correctly, using the path to the resource bundle:

```swift
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TheBundleName", ofType: "bundle")
let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath!)
```

Despite all this, I'm still encountering the problem. I'm curious to understand why this is happening and what I can do to make it work with the bundle. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem somehow lies in either

- that I created this bundle as a new target → macOS → bundle?
- or, that it is missing the `Resources` folder

I now manually recreated the bundle as a simple folder with a `.bundle` extension and `Resources` subfolder, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277452/38729, and it seems to work as expected.