# creating bundle for ios xcode app

Tags: ios, bash, shell, bundle

I have created a bundle from the shell  [using this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578496/creating-my-own-bundle-in-xcode-for-iphone-application)

it creates the bundle file fine, so i just add to this package contents, what I need,

but the actual script is not working properly [as it wants a ./assets folder]

this are my steps:

1. nano scripto

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 

   echo "Building assets bundle."
   if [ -d ./MyAssets.bundle ]; then
    rm ./MyAssets.bundle/*
   else
    mkdir ./MyAssets.bundle
   fi
   find ./assets -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -J% cp % ./MyAssets.bundle
   ```
2. save it,
3. $chmod +x scripto
4. $./scripto

so it works fine, but in order to have it working with out problems, I want to get rid of the find ./assets

so how do I modify the script to avoid this `./assets` folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find ./assets ...` is just copying all the files under the directory named `assets` to the directory "MyAssets.bundle".  If you are manually copying your assets to the MyAssets.bundle you can just remove the last line from the script, or comment it out by placing a # just before the find.  Note: if you run this script after placing files in MyAssets.bundle, those files will be deleted.